# Script for Automatic Upgrade Codes in Jupyter Nootbooks to Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, upgrade, tensorflow2.0

Is there a script to automatically upgrade Jupyter Nootbook .ipynb files (or Colab) to Tensorflow 2 as in for [the .py python files](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade)? If not, any work arounds to this?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is, check this:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade

1- You download the python file

2- usage:

```
tf_upgrade_v2 [-h] [--infile INPUT_FILE] [--outfile OUTPUT_FILE]
                     [--intree INPUT_TREE] [--outtree OUTPUT_TREE]
                     [--copyotherfiles COPY_OTHER_FILES] [--inplace]
                     [--reportfile REPORT_FILENAME] [--mode {DEFAULT,SAFETY}]
                     [--print_all]
```